# scala reassignment to val in Option Class

Tags: scala, option-type, nonetype

My code looks like:

```
    case class SRecord(trialId: String, private var _max:Int)    {
      def max=_max 
      def max_=(value:Int):Unit=_max=value
     }
```

Then later on I apply a function onto it:

```
def groupSummaryRecords(it:Iterator[Option[SRecord]],   optionSummary:Option[SRecord]):Option[SRecord] = {
    var max=0;
    var sRecord1 : Option[SRecord] = None 
    var i=0
    while(it.hasNext) {
        var sRecord:Option[SRecord] = it.next();
        if(i==0) {
            sRecord1 = sRecord;
        }
        ..
    }
    sRecord1.max=max; // getting 'reassignment to val' compilation error
    ..
 }
```

**Why am i getting this compilation error, and how to fix it ?**

If I instead change sRecord and sRecord1 instances to be of type `SRecord` instead of `Option[SRecord]` as well as the method signature, it all works fine however.

But in some cases I may have a null `SRecord` hence the use of `None/Some`. I am new to Scala, using `Option/Some` all over feels like a real pain if you ask me, i am just thinking of removing all this `Option` nonsense and testing for 'null' in good ol' Java, at least my code would work ??!

Comment: what are you trying to do here?

Comment: a general tip: avoid case classes with mutable state (vars) -- just make it a regular class unless you really want to do pattern-matching with it.

Comment: Don't use null. Maybe reading this article will help with the problems you are facing with the use of Option http://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/12/19/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-5-the-option-type.html

Comment: thanks, i already did read the article, but it didn't help for this question .. ; ok @RobStarling , i thought using a case class would automatically define my getter methods, so it would be helpful.

Comment: @matthieulieber it's true that you get that nice benefit, but you will also get weird side effects, like `==` comparisons that ignore the mutable bits.

Comment: e.g. given `case class A(x: Int, y: Int) { var _z: Int = 0; def z=_z; def z_=(z: Int):Unit=_z=z };` and `val a=A(1,2)` and `val b=A(1,2)` then `a==b` is `true` even if you change one of their `z`s, like `a.z=7`.

Comment: for a plain, fully-public, mutable container like a C `struct`, you probably just want `class B(var x: Int, var y: Int);`

Comment: thanks for the explanation @RobStarling !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the line `sRecord1.max=max` you are trying to call the `max` method on an `Option[SRecord]`, not an `SRecord`. You want to access the contained `SRecord` (if any) and call the method on that, which can be done using foreach:

```
sRecord1.foreach(_.max=max)
```

which is desugared to:

```
sRecord1.foreach( srec => srec.max=max )
```

(the actual name "srec" is made up, the compiler will assign some internal name, but you get the idea). If `sRecord1` is `None`, this won't do anything, but if it is `Some(srec)`, the method execution will be passed in to operate on the contained instance.